# I'll give you the instructions, you give me the answer

Tags: riddle, no-computers

```
- perform handshake
- install es on both ends
- pause process in exce
- swap chang.exe
- combine previous and modify
- terminate communication
```

Hint 1

> The answer is an 8 letter word

Comment: Does this is related to rot13(Pbirevat n obbx)

Comment: @Swati no it does not.

Comment: @Kable is the answer (rot 13) Rkpunatr

Comment: @LakshaySura Lrf, pna lbh rkcynva nyy gur pyhrf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the answer is

> exchange

- perform handshake

> Exchange greetings

- install es on both ends

> It has an e on either end

- pause process in exce

> Pause process = hang, inside exce is excHANGe

- swap chang.exe

> anagram of exchange

- combine previous and modify

> previous = ex, modify = change, combine to "exchange"

- terminate communication

Comment: Yep, well done.

Comment: I was pretty much confused about 3rd one. Congrats to figure that out.+1

Answer (score 6):

This sounds to me like

> Instructions on how to tie shoes

Because

> - perform handshake
>  - install es on both ends
>  - pause process in exce
>  - swap chang.exe
>  - combine previous and modify
>  - terminate communication 
>  OR
>  - Start out by crossing the laces
>  - Prepare both sides with loops
>  - Wait a second to get the hold correct
>  - Cross hands with the lace assemblies
>  - Interlock the lace assemblies and shift for tightness
>  - Shoes tied
>  Note- I don't tie my shoes like this, but am convinced this sounds like a method I've heard of.

Comment: Nice guess, but that’s not it.

Comment: Nice @MacGyver88